# How do I install libXp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

This is what I get upon entering `sudo yum -y install libXp.x86_64`:

```
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

[image]

When I run `yum repolist all`, I get `repolist: 0`. What should I do?

**EDIT**: I just read that `yum` is only for Red Hat. So, since I am using Ubuntu, I wrote: `sudo apt-get install libX`. On typing that, I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libXp.x86_64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXp.x86_64'
```

Comment: You can see the available repos in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory

Comment: That means you don't have any repo. You can add your own repo file inside that directory.

Comment: How? I don't know anything! I need it urgently. So please, if you can help, please help soon. I need to install `libXp.x86_64`, whatever that is. And since I just found somewhere that `yum` is apparently only for RedHat, and my server is Ubuntu, I tried `sudo apt-get install libXp.x86_64`. And that give sthe following error: `E: Unable to locate package libXp.x86_64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXp.x86_64'
`. So, please help me.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and then `sudo synaptic`. Use the GUI to search for your package(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Upon writing these 2 lines, I get this error: `(synaptic:17960): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

Comment: If you want to install a desktop environment, try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`. What are you actually trying to do? What did you install?

Comment: I don't know what I am required to do. There is a guy who has given me some lines to execute, and this line involving `yum` is not working. I don't know what these lines of code do. All I know is, I NEED them working ASAP!

Comment: search package name by `apt-cache search libXp`, check if it exists  and install by `sudo apt-get install libXp`. you dont need `.x86_64`. note that package name may differ between yum an apt. (e.g. libXp might be something like libXp2 )

Comment: Also, since it's not actually a programming question, you should ask http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ next time when you have similar question.

Comment: @ymonad Or, in OP's case [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Why are you diverting into Synaptic and desktop environments?  The OP wants to install a single library -- you are going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yum isn't limited to Redhat, just as Apt-get isn't limited to Ubuntu.

But "apt-get" is the "native" package handler for all Debian-based Linux distros, including Ubuntu.

So when you see "yum install xyz"; you should mentally substitute "sudo apt-get install xyz".

Here is a good tutorial on "apt-get" and friends:

[Apt get tutorial – manage packages on ubuntu/debian](http://www.binarytides.com/apt-get-tutorial-package-management-ubuntu-commandline/)

ADDENDUM: I believe this command might help: `sudo apt-get install libxp6`

Comment: Then why is it not working?

Comment: Q: What exactly are you trying to install (what package "needs" libXp)?  Q: Are you running a 64-bit OS (please run `uname -a`, and pst the output)?  Q: Are you running from a GUI desktop, or from a command line (Synaptic requires a GUI)?  Please try `sudo apt-get install libxp6`, and please update your post with answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The package names in Debian (and derivatives such as Ubuntu) are lowercase (unlike rpm names which can be mixed-case).  You could get the package using

```
sudo apt-get install libxp6
```

Once installed:

```
$ dpkg -L libxp6
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libxp6
/usr/share/doc/libxp6/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libxp6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxp6/changelog.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6
```

For browsing, the [`aptitude`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/) application is a better way to go because it shows the actual package names, and allows searching.  (For whatever reason, the analogous [GUI application's](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) database does not appear to include *all* packages, merely the most popular: I have not found it useful).

For additional information:

- [Debian package naming convention?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97289/debian-package-naming-convention)
- [Basics of the Debian package management system](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)  (The Debian GNU/Linux FAQ, Chapter 7)